# Sendmail with time and pause using Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code e works perfectly, however, I want to set a time to send each email.

Example: 100 e-mail is sent, the PAUSE script for 1 hour, and sends back another 100 emails.

This code here it sends direct. I need to make the 2 work, and send emails slowly according to the txt list.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
## use: perl send.pl list-email.txt "noreply@mail.com" "subject" html.html

$ARGC = @ARGV;

if ( $ARGC != 4 ) {
    printf "$0 <mailist> <tes@test.com> <HELLO friend> <html.htm>\n\n";
    #printf "Script for sending emails";
    exit(1);
}

$mailtype = "content-type: text/html";
$sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$sender   = $ARGV[1];
$subject  = $ARGV[2];
$efile    = $ARGV[0];
$emar     = $ARGV[0];
$count    = 1;
open( FOO, $ARGV[3] );
@foo = <FOO>;
$corpo = join( "\n", @foo );

open( BANDFIT, "$emar" ) || die "Can't Open $emar";

while (<BANDFIT>) {
    ( $ID, $options ) = split( /\|/, $_ );
    chop($options);

    foreach ($ID) {
        $recipient = $ID;

        open( SENDMAIL, "| $sendmail -t" );
        print SENDMAIL "$mailtype\n";
        print SENDMAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
        print SENDMAIL "From: $sender\n";
        print SENDMAIL "To: $recipient\n\n";
        print SENDMAIL "$corpo\n\n";
        close(SENDMAIL);

        printf "Enviado para $recipient [ OK $count ]";
        $count++;
    }
}
close(BANDFIT);
```

=============== other code / time pause===============

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub mostraMensagem() {
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        print("Hello World!\n");
        $count++;

        if ( $count == 5 ) {
            print("PAUSE!\n");
            $count = 0;
            sleep(5);
            print("CONTINUE..\n");
            mostraMensagem;
        }
    }
}

mostraMensagem;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. At least, I hope it's not as simple as adding `sleep(3600);` to your script.

Comment: Somewhat OT, but a good read: http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices/

Comment: Actually... what's that sub trying to do? It looks like it it's recursive, but doing it inside an infinite while loop? That seems very dirty. Am I missing something?

Comment: I want to make a sender to send 100 emails per hour through the perl shell. only that ... the list has 2,000 contacts and I want to send 100 e-mail every hour. you see?
The first code sends 2,000 emails directly without pause, it is working perfectly. wanted to add a pause on it, sending 100 emails from the list (txt) every 1 hour. thanks all for asked

Comment: What is the purpose of wanting to send 100 emails every hour instead of just sending the 2000? I'd much rather deal with the ~10 minutes of script performance time vs the 20 hours. I would recommend just sending the 2000 emails and move on to something else. Email campaign solutions don't do split timing because it gives performance degradation. Over long periods of time for some companies.

Comment: @NicholasLAnderson 1 hour was only one example for ease of explanation. I am Brazilian and I can not explain in English. I agree with you. Sorry, I'm no programmer, tell me which part of the code that I add your code, please ... thanks for help, its great
I tried but I could not ..
how would the whole code? please help me ... u are great

Comment: can you post a small example (2-3 lines) of your list-email.txt? I would assume just a list of emails but I see you are splitting the lines for some reason.

Comment: root@mx:~/teste# perl send.pl maillist.txt "noreply@test.com" "subject" mensage.html
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got friends !! but still need you ...

it sends 5 emails and pause for 5 seconds, however, the count does not continue, it returns to zero. what can we do?

the counter back to zero after 5 ..

The new CODE:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
## use: perl enviar.pl list-mail.txt "my@mail.com" "subject" html.html


$ARGC=@ARGV;

if ($ARGC !=4) {

printf "$0 <mailist> <my@myemail.com> <subject> <msg.htm>\n\n";

#printf "Script sending emails";

  exit(1);

} 


$mailtype = "content-type: text/html";

$sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

$sender = $ARGV[1];
$subject = $ARGV[2];
$efile = $ARGV[0];
$emar = $ARGV[0];
$count=1;

open(FOO, $ARGV[3]); 
@foo = <FOO>;

$corpo = join("\n", @foo);
open (BANDFIT, "$emar") || die "Can't Open $emar";

while(<BANDFIT>)        {


($ID,

$options) = split(/\|/,$_);

chop($options);

 foreach ($ID) {

$recipient = $ID;
## this changes =>>> ###
### send 5 email of list.txt, and pause 5 seconds, continue.. ### 

if ( $count == 5 ) {

           print("PAUSE!\n");
           $count = 0;
          sleep(5);
          print("CONTINUE..\n");
}

open (SENDMAIL, "| $sendmail -t");
print SENDMAIL "$mailtype\n";
print SENDMAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
print SENDMAIL "From: $sender\n";
print SENDMAIL "To: $recipient\n\n";
print SENDMAIL "$corpo\n\n";
close (SENDMAIL);

printf "sending for $recipient [ Ok Send; $count ]";
$count++;
}

} 
close(BANDFIT);

#### end #####
```

Comment: You'll need to add a new variable to track the total number of emails sent.

Comment: Añadir una segunda variable que hará un seguimiento del número total de mensajes de correo electrónico enviados. No restablezca la variable cuando detenerse.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you would count the amount of emails sent, when you reach the 100 mark, pause for 3600 seconds and then continue.

** UDPATE - Full Code **

Tested (smaller numbers) on RHEL 5

Assuming email-list.txt looks like:

```
user_1_@company.com
user_2_@company.com
user_99_@company.com
user_100_@company.com
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# =========================
# Assign $ARGV[x] -> var
# =========================
if (@ARGV < 4){ usage() }

my $sendAs          =   $ARGV[1];
my $subject         =   $ARGV[2];
my $htmlFile        =   $ARGV[3];
my $sendList        =   $ARGV[0];

# =========================
# Get Send List -> var
# =========================
open(LIST, $sendList) || die "Could not open $sendList: $!\n";
    my @recipients = <LIST>;
close(LIST);

# =========================
# Iterate / Send Email
# =========================
my $count = 1;

foreach my $recipient (@recipients)
{
    chomp($recipient);

    if  ( $count < 100 )
    {
        my $cmd = 'cat ' . $htmlFile . ' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s "$(echo -e "' . $subject . '\nContent-Type: text/html")" ' . $recipient . ' -v -- -F ' . $sendAs;
        my $results = `$cmd`;
    }
    elsif ( $count == 100 )
    {
        my $cmd = 'cat ' . $htmlFile . ' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s "$(echo -e "' . $subject . '\nContent-Type: text/html")" ' . $recipient . '  -- -F ' . $sendAs;
        my $results = `$cmd`;

        sleep(3600);
        $count = 0;
    }
    $count++;
}

# =========================
# Essential Subroutines
# =========================
sub usage()
{
    print "\nUsage:\n\t$0 <mailist.txt> <test\@mail.com> <\"Hello friend\"> <test.html>\n\n";
    exit;
}
```

**P.S. LEARN PERL**

Comment: 1 hour was only one example for ease of explanation. I am Brazilian and I can not explain in English. I agree with you. Sorry, I'm no programmer, tell me which part of the code that I add your code, please ...  thanks for help, its great

Comment: yes, please ... code complete. you is great ... I do not understand perl. sorry.

Comment: I will add complete code shortly. I'll have to post in English as I don't know Spanish.

Comment: my list and just like your example. email above and another below. I tested the code and gave the following error: sh: 1: Email: not found. i tried perl send.pl list.txt "my@mysite.com" "subject" mensage.html

Comment: `root@mx:~/teste# perl send.pl maillist.txt "noreply@test.com" "subject" mensage.html
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found
sh: 1: mail: not found
`

Comment: Try running: yum install -y mail mailx sendmail

Comment: i using postfix.. I tried sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

Comment: E: Package 'mailx' has no installation candidate

Comment: In the script try changing it to use the full path, /usr/sbin/sendmail or /bin/mail